# No such partition after deleting ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, android

I has windows and ubuntu in dual-boot. Once I logged in Windows and erased ubuntu partition. After that I've got a "no such partition" error with a blanking grub prompt.

Now the problem is that I'm on a bus right now with unrooted Samsung S7 with an SD card. Is there any way to use it as a live cd?

Comment: grub's config files are stored on the partition you just erased. if the sd card is seen by grub you can boot from it

Comment: Also duplicate of [Is it possible to install Ubuntu FROM a smartphone?](https://askubuntu.com/q/277306/301745)