# My windows 10 does not working, Now I want to install Ubuntu only

Tags: system-installation, windows

So, first, I tried to reset my PC but unfortunately, it didn't boot up. I tried to fix it through troubleshooting. I tried every possible solution to fix it. But, it never worked. It only say, "automatic repair cannot repair your PC" or something similar like that. It does not even reset. I am in real trouble. Nothing is working.

Finally, I decided to install ubuntu freshly and only Ubuntu. I don't want windows anymore. I don't have any other PC to do that. I have only a phone which has 3 gb ram. Can I able install ubuntu? If yes, please help me.

Comment: I would use another borrowed machine (maybe hard given lockdowns due covid19) https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-verify-your-ubuntu-download/14010 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016
downloading on phone is easy, but writing to install media not so. Can make your PC boot from network? (PXE like) but a borrowed pc is easier.

Comment: Is your phone Apple or Android? What;'s the make and model of your PC? Some versions of Ubuntu work better on older, slower PCs. Please provide the model number (you get that from the same sticker as the serial number) and the make, then click [edit] and paste that information into your question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install Ubuntu FROM a smartphone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277306/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-from-a-smartphone)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [rooted Android phone](https://www.androidcentral.com/root), you can download an [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or [Ubuntu flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) ISO file to your phone, then install the [DriveDroid](https://softwarebakery.com//projects/drivedroid) app to make your phone imitate a LiveUSB (the normal installation tool for Ubuntu).

You will need to choose the [Ubuntu flavour appropriate for your PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar).

Once all that's completed, the official installation instructions for Ubuntu and its flavours [are found here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).

Answer (score 0):

I found this googling about your problem. 
It show a way to make a part of the momeory of your android phone in a bootable media.

[Here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/recover-pc-using-android/)